# How to use query-replace(-regexp) non-(semi-)interactively in a command?

Tags: query-replace

The title isn't entirely accurate. By "non-interactively" I
mean, for lack of a better term, "semi-interactively". In a regular
call through `M-%` or `M-x query-replace`, the command could be called interactive
in two ways: 1) by giving the string to replace and the replacement 2)
by choosing one by one which matches to replace. The idea is to skip
the former step by giving fixed arguments (string-to-replace and
replacement-string), but to keep the latter interactive query
behavior.

Often a *queried* search & replace task needs to be repeated over time
(i.e. search and replace the same strings) so the obvious next step is
to write a simple command, for example, to create a
`fix-two-or-more-spaces` command replacing `" \\{2,\\}"` with a
single space.  How to achieve this?  Must admit I got a little
intimidated by `perform-replace`...

Comment: Do you want to run a query-replace, or a replace? In the latter case, the doc string for `perform-replace` already contains the answer: use `re-search-forward` plus `replace-match`

Comment: Don't be overwhelmed by `perform-replace` its usage is simple in simple use-cases. Example: `(perform-replace "\\([[:space:]]\\)\\{2,\\}" "\\1" t t nil)`.

Comment: @rpluim Thought it was clearly stated in the title and in the description; it is a `query-replace`

Comment: You said both `query-replace` and "non-interactively". `query-replace` is inherently interactive, hence my comment

Comment: @rpluim That's a good point that was ignored completely! Just made some changes to the question, hoping it is better explained this time.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks, I'm experimenting with it to grasp its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is rather crude but got it to work. (Went lazy on the names.)
Suggestions welcome!

```el
;; Main function. A wrapper around ‘perform-replace’
(defun alt-query-replace-wrapper (to-replace replacement is-regexp)
  (apply 'perform-replace to-replace replacement t is-regexp nil nil nil
         ;; Last argument as a list for ‘apply’.
         (and (use-region-p)
              ;; Do replacements only on region or rectangle, if
              ;; there's one.
              (list (region-beginning)
                    (region-end)
                    nil
                    (region-noncontiguous-p)))))

;; An example command
(defun fix-two-or-more-blank-spaces ()
  (interactive)
  (alt-query-replace-wrapper " \\{2,\\}" " " t))
```